# passport-azure-ad fail? "Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: We did not receive a token we know how to validate"

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I am trying to authenticate an Angular SPA user to use a node API with passport-azure-ad .

The SPA using msal appears to do the log in process ok and send a bearer token. In the API, passport gives this message in the log and doesn’t authenticate the token.

{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":,"pid":18992,"level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: We did not receive a token we know how to validate","time":"2020-11-16T09:05:39.130Z","v":0}
In the passport log I can see it has decoded the JWT.

Documentation and tutorials on MS haven't offered explanation.

Is this is an issue or configuration?

On jwt.ms the token looks like this ( with sensitive stuff removed)

```js
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "kid": "1LTMzakihiRla_8z2BEJVXeWMqo"
}.{
  "ver": "2.0",
  "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<removed>/v2.0",
  "sub": "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFCJjacUizahSCD5TPfL4H8",
  "aud": "35a82220-37b8-4379-8787-2e9d399a5a11",
  "exp": 1605521138,
  "iat": 1605517238,
  "nbf": 1605517238,
  "name": "<removed>",
  "preferred_username": "<removed>",
  "oid": "00000000-0000-0000-47f4-b9a2c8265a4e",
  "tid": "<removed>",
  "azp": "6a595665-21c0-418c-b53c-11a53261ea1f",
  "scp": "access_as_user",
  "azpacr": "0",
  "aio": "DZrm9qwwNRshPep3OC!5Fye8RReC2f7Xweml1tg1DrjBTMaCJjSf6tZiPIm!Xu0I79vhJZwsyPjKWgp0FR9o0v7s4AWBaO9iLOl0qWJx6mznYOR6nwmpv7LREoQts9Ixe49O*HvvyaCsmcuh1iXcnq8$"
}.[Signature]
```

That token was created for a user added to AD as a guest user.

### Configuration (with tenant id removed)

#### AD

Two registered applications, SPA and API with authentication set to multi tenant and personal Microsoft accounts. With one API scope granted to the SPA, “access_as_user”

#### Angular SPA

Angular 7
@azure/msal-angular 1.1.2

MSAL config

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MessageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      auth: {
        clientId: '6a595665-21c0-418c-b53c-11a53261ea1f',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
      },
      cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'localStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
      },
    },
    {
      popUp: !isIE,
      unprotectedResources: [],
      consentScopes: [
        "api://35a82220-37b8-4379-8787-2e9d399a5a11/access_as_user"
      ],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['http://localhost:3000', ['api://35a82220-37b8-4379-8787-2e9d399a5a11/access_as_user']]
      ],
      extraQueryParameters: {}
    })
    ],
  providers: [HttpClient,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    MsalService,
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### NodeJs API

passport 0.4.1
passport-azure-ad 4.3.0

node config

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

var passport = require('passport');

var BearerStrategy = require("passport-azure-ad").BearerStrategy;

var options =  {
    identityMetadata:"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<removed>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration",
    clientID:"35a82220-37b8-4379-8787-2e9d399a5a11",
    loggingLevel: "info",
    passReqToCallback: false,
    isB2C:false,
    validateIssuer:false,
    loggingNoPII: false
  };

  var bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options, function(token, done) {
    console.log("verifying token");
    console.log("token");
    done(null, {}, token);
  });

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  passport.use(bearerStrategy);

const port = 3000

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

app.get('/',passport.authenticate("oauth-bearer", { session: false }),(req, res) => {
    res.send('{"msg":"Hello SPA this is the API!"}');
  }
)

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})'
```

Comment: have you checked that if there is a public key with id "1LTMzakihiRla_8z2BEJVXeWMqo" on https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant>/discovery/v2.0/keys ?

Comment: Thanks Stanley I cant see that page for my tenant id.

Comment: But I have fixed this problem changing Azure App Config to use Single Tenant. That's OK for my use case. Be good to know relationship of public key to when it was configured as Multi Tenant + Personal Accounts on a B2B AD. One of the MS guides mentions creating public keys when registering apps, other tutorials I recall don't. It's confusing ....